# http status code 500 / webpage stops refreshing

Tags: c#, javascript, html, vbscript

WE have an intranet webpage which is used to display information to works on monitors around our site. This webpage is automatically refreshed every 15 seconds.

All this works find, until the Database server has a problem and the webpage and no longer get a connection, and we get an error back normally an HTTP 500 error.

My solution to this has been to write a C# application that checks the HTTP status of the webpage, and if a HTTP 500 is found to close the browser and then reopen it again and display the webpage.
This application is using a timer event set to ever 30 seconds.

The problem I am having is my C# application does not always pick up the 500 error, or any other error that may cause the webpage to stop refreshing.

Below is the code I have written to try and check for the error(s)

```
public static void Check_Process()
{
    Console.Write("checking started at {0}" + Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now);
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(txt_url);

        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        // Read the error stream first and then wait.
        string error = someProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();


        Console.Write(error);
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;

            if ((int)response.StatusCode == 500)
            {
                Console.Write((int)response.StatusCode + " error found at {0}" + Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now);
                Close_webpage();
                Start_webpage();
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.Write((int)response.StatusCode + " error found at {0}" + Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now);
                Close_webpage();
                Start_webpage();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The webpage is currently loaded from within the application using

```
public static void Start_webpage()
{
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    startInfo.FileName = "IExplore.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = txt_url;
    someProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

Hoping someone can point out where I have gone wrong, or a better way of doing this, as currently we are have to manually refresh/reload the webpage.

Comment: Something besides to fix the web app so it doesn't 500?

Comment: You should do something when  if (e.Status != WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) -- The app didn't throw an exception just so you could ignore it when e.Status wasn't that one value. The app is trying to communicate something, don't discard that clue.

Comment: If it's an error on the server, why would restarting the browser help?

Comment: the 500 error is caused by exceeding the number of users we are allowed to have access to the database, and at this point in time the company do NOT want to increase the licence so we have to suffer, and find ways around things like this

Comment: as suggested above I have put a little extra code in to check e.Status != WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError. This has not shed any more light.

Except it looks to me likes it does not exit the catch (WebException e)
as I never see the "checking started at " message line after a few rotations

Answer (score 0):

Do you do a complete page reload ?

How about you use ajax call instead ? You can put that in setInterval/setTimeout, and then process successful/failed responses - should make it resistant to service failures, and more user-friendly.

And yes, you probably should eliminate 500. Try/catch{msg("OMG, database is not accessible!")} type of thing :)

Ah, and the issue with your code could be the fact that your code checks database and its fine, but then the 500th user connects, and your page refresh fails.

Comment: Doing a complete page reload is what I am trying to achieve. The problem has been detecting the error when it occurs.